# What should I put in the CLAIMED-SCORE field in my CQ WPX RTTY log?

Tags: contest, logging

I have dabbled in contests mainly to collect states and entities, and have occasionally sent in check logs. I just worked the CQ WPX RTTY contest, and would like to submit my logs for credit but the primitive logging system I used doesn't calculate the score. To compute a "claimed score" requires me to determine the number of unique prefixes.

Frankly, I'd rather not compute a score at all and just let the contest organizers do it (since they will anyhow). I wonder what the "claimed score" is used for - perhaps in cases where there is a large discrepancy between the claimed score and their computed score they take a look at the log?

I'll add that for the 2023 CQ WW DX SSB where I submitted check logs, they sent me information that showed how my logs were scored including QSOs that were disallowed - it was very interesting and useful.

What should I fill in for the CLAIMED-SCORE field?

Comment: Can't answer your question about a Python script, yet: sending in a claimed score with your log is not strictly necessary. Upon receipt of a log, the organisers will calculate a "raw" i.e. unchecked score anyway before they begin their log checking procedures.

Comment: @henryflower Thanks, I just submitted my log, leaving out a CLAIMED-SCORE and it didn't flag any errors. In past contests, to submit a "check log" the instructions said to set the CLAIMED-SCORE to 0.

Comment: Voting to close a duplicate of [this question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/how-can-i-tell-if-a-call-sign-is-valid) and you should specifically [look at this answer](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/11915/1550), though there are several helpful answers for you at that question post. Rock on!

Comment: I edited the question to address the real issue. @gschro, feel free to submit your comment as an answer - you appear to have answered your own question!